# Faily certain that my scanning script is treating the input as a string and not as a list as intended. Can anyone explain this?

Tags: python, string, list, exception, input

I have a site scanner, its not the best but it works. However now I am getting an exception whenever i am prompted to select a list. Its treating the .txt file as a string and not a file. Because when in input it into the site scanning tool which allows for either directly scanning using a .txt list of sites OR also allows you to input a string to search and grab the sites containing that string from bing THEN perform the initial scan using the grabbed sitelist, which is written as follows:

```
try:
    Target = raw_input('Input your site list: ')
    TEXTList= open(Target, 'r').read().splitlines()
```

and the exception that is raised if the input is string and not a .txt file/file location is

```
except:
    try:
        qs = raw_input(' -Do You want search Bing for [{}] (y/n)? '.format(sys.argv[1]))
```

It is currently throwing the exception when i search for newly created 9-21.txt resulting in:

```
"Do  you want to search Bing for "9-21.txt" (y/n)?
```

However inputting the much, much older `9-20.txt` results in the scan being started without the bing search exception...

What is the issue with the text file. Im assuming that HAS to be it... but i figured showing the code would help explain the situation.

Comment: What exception is it getting?

Comment: The first argument to `open()` has to be a filename.

Comment: It is a file name but its not treating it as one.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ukeqkn

Comment: Are you sure the file exists? You should print the exception so you know the reason why it's going into the `except` block.

Comment: Or get rid of `try/except` while you're debugging it, so it will stop when it gets an error.